# How to use PHP in_array() function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to see if multiple values are in a wordpress category. How do I go about checking for multiple categories using in_array()?

```
if ( in_array( 13, $cats ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I need to check for categories: 13, 210, 311, 312

**EDIT**

Full code:

```
function lw_gpf_exclude_product($excluded, $product_id, $feed_format) {
    // Return TRUE to exclude a product, FALSE to include it, $excluded to use the default behaviour.
    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    if ( in_array( 13, $cats ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return $excluded;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: It would depend on what your array looks like.  Post what you've tried with the output it generates.

Comment: @ivanivan looks like this `array( 'fields' => 'ids' )`

Comment: You should ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ 
Also you could have elaborated on your code, cause you got 3 answears, but I fear that there is more to your question

Comment: @TreyCopeland Hopefully this is what you were looking for. I updated my answear with 2 methods of check. Also this questions place should be on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: You want to check if a product is in a particular product category? Couldn't you then use the WordPress function, [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is really ambiguos I presume you want to check if 13, 210, 311, 312 are in $cats, then us this snippet:

```php
<?php
$array = array( 13, 210, 311, 312 );
$cats  = array( 13, 210, 111111, 5555, 66666, 77777, 311, 312 );
if( $array == array_intersect( $array, $cats ) ){
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So I think I know what you want, but I'm not sure. Anyways here is the updated function.

```php
function lw_gpf_exclude_product($excluded, $product_id, $feed_format) {
    // Return TRUE to exclude a product, FALSE to include it, $excluded to use the default behaviour.
    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms
    // check to make sure the response in not wp error, see Return Values
    if( ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ){
        $check = array( 13, 210, 311, 312 );
        $ids = array();
        // each array element is an object, see Variables in Returned Object
        // method 1: more reliable
        foreach( $cats as $cat ){
            $ids[] = $cat->term_id;
        }
        if( $check == array_intersect( $check, $ids ) ){
            return true;
        }
        // method 2: just compares the number of elements found
        $check = array( 13, 210, 311, 312 );
        $count = 0;
        foreach( $cats as $cat ){
            if( in_array( $cat->term_id, $check ) ){
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if( $count === count( $check ) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return $excluded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach looop for check all categories like

```
$array = array('mykey' => 'myvalue', 'mykey2'=> 'myvalue2', 'mykey3'=> 'myvalueN');
foreach($array as $key=> $item){
  if ( in_array( $key, $cats ) ) {
      echo "Key or id is available";
  }
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop

```
<?php
$categories = [13, 210, 311, 312];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
if (in_array ($category, $cats) {
echo "{$category} is in array!";
}
}
?>
```